# Prevent deleting Account related documents from ContentDocumentLink

Tags: apex, trigger

How to prevent deleting account-related documents from ContentDocument. If any document is associated with any account then I want to prevent deleting it.

```
SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, LinkedEntity.Type, ContentDocumentId 
FROM ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE ContentDocumentId = '<Content Document Id>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this for ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink trigger behavior in Classic and Lightning - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312746&type=1&mode=1

For lightning experience, write a trigger on ContentDocument Object for before delete event. In the code, look if the document is linked with the account(Query on ContentDocumentLink), then prevent deletion by using addError().

**Sample Code:**

```
trigger ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument(before delete) {
  if (Trigger.isDelete) {
    Set<Id> accountAssociatedDocIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (ContentDocumentLink docLink : [
      SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntity.Type
      FROM ContentDocumentLink
      WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :Trigger.oldMap.keySet()
    ]) {
      if (docLink.LinkedEntity?.Type == 'Account') {
        accountAssociatedDocIds.add(docLink.ContentDocumentId);
      }
    }
    if (!accountAssociatedDocIds.isEmpty()) {
      for (ContentDocument doc : Trigger.oldMap.values()) {
        if (accountAssociatedDocIds.contains(doc.Id)) {
          doc.addError(
            'You cannot delete This Document. Since it is linked to Account.'
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample for how to look if the document is linked with the account(Query on ContentDocumentLink)

Comment: Updated Answer with Sample Code.